# How can I access my php.ini file using Plesk?

Tags: php

I want to know how I can access my `php.ini` using Plesk. I'm looking everywhere and can't seem to find it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's available—you'll need to login to the server via SSH, FTP (with root, which is unlikely), or SFTP and view `/etc/php.ini`. As far as I am aware, Plesk does allow overrides by default in `.htaccess` or `ini_set` in `.php` files.